# Reserve memory on OS X

Tags: c, macos, memory-management

What's the equivalent to Windows's `VirtualAlloc` in OS X? That is, how can i reserve a contiguous address space without actually commiting it and then commit chunks of it later?

Thanks,

Alex

Comment: AFAIK, there's no way to reserve memory as `VirtualAlloc` does. For contiguous allocation use `mmap`.

Comment: I have also seen `mmap` used for contiguous allocation on OS X and other Unices. Could a specialist point out the differences, if any, with Windows' `VirtualAlloc`? Perhaps someone who has answered that they weren't the same? (Note: the users of `mmap` I was referring to went back to `malloc` but I can't remember the reason)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`mmap()`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/mmap.2.html) function, called with `MAP_ANON | MAP_PRIVATE`, is very roughly equivalent to `VirtualAlloc()` with the `MEM_RESERVE` flag.  Memory is then committed by touching each page in the mapping.

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately, there is no exact equivalent to `VirtualAlloc`.